# In what ways was Maimonides an influence on Spinoza?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, spinoza

As someone with an intense interest in Arabic Neoplatonism (in particular Ibn Sina), I have a passing familiarity with Maimonides. (I am considering reading The Guide for the Perplexed after I finish the largest of my current readings (Critique of Practical Reason). If you had any secondary reading recommendations I would greatly appreciate it.) Until today I was unaware of the link between Maimonides and Spinoza and read that Spinoza may have become familiar with Aristotle through Maimonides. In what was does Maimonides 'inform' Spinoza?

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, however it may help fill in a piece of the puzzle at some point in your research, Title: The legend of the Middle Ages : philosophical explorations of medieval Christianity, Judaism, and Islam Author: Brague, Rémi, 1947-  Publisher:University of Chicago Press,Pub date:2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can see [Maimonides](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/maimonides/#Con) for some hint and: Joshua Parens, [Maimonides and Spinoza: Their Conflicting Views of Human Nature](https://books.google.it/books?id=Sr8u88jtoVgC&printsec=frontcover), University of Chicago Press (2012)

See also: Steven Nadler (editor), [Spinoza and Medieval Jewish Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=_lNEBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2015), page 4:

> It is nearly impossible to write about the *Tractatus Theologico-Politicus* without discussing Maimonides, primarily because Spinoza explicitly takes the author of the *Guide of the Perplexed* to task for his account of the interpretation of Scripture.

Finally, see: Steven Nadler, [Spinoza's Heresy: Immortality and the Jewish Mind](https://books.google.it/books?id=bxCm-mzkW1UC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2001), for an account of Spinoza's view about the mind (page ix):

> While it is true that the Cartesian context is the truly important one when it comes to understanding Spinoza’s metaphysics and epistemology—essentially, Parts One and Two of the *Ethics*—this is not the case with respect to his moral philosophy, and particularly his account of virtue, human happiness, and the eternity of the mind.
>
> Cartesian philosophy may have laid the ‘first principles’ for the conclusions
> that Spinoza draws in Parts Four and Five of the *Ethics*, but the doctrines that we find embedded in the propositions of those parts are a response to a far different tradition, one that has as its most prominent members the medieval Jewish philosophers Maimonides and Gersonides.

Comment: Also helpful are Warren Harvey's "A Portrait of Spinoza as a Maimonidean" and Alexander Green's "A Portrait of Spinoza as a Maimonidean Reconsidered."